# Azure Traffic Manager fault tolerance

Tags: networking, azure, fault-tolerance

I have just answered [Do I need Azure Traffic Manager with Azure API Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923358/do-i-need-azure-traffic-manager-with-azure-api-services/35924325#35924325) Over on SO

Part of my answer was understanding the failure of all aspects of a solution to which I realised I really don't understand the fault tolerance of Traffic Manager.

If I have a solution hosted in two regions with a Traffic Manager profile spread across them, and an Azure region dies, what prevents Traffic Manager from failing also.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Traffic Manager is one of Azure's globally scoped services. In other words, it is not bound to a specific region and is redundant across all Azure regions by design. Your Traffic Manager profile would live in all regions so would not fail with a region.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services